# Tensorflow 1.15, Keras 2.2.5, on_batch_end or on_train_batch_end not triggering

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is my custom callblack:

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
          print("on_train_begin")
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
          print("on_train_batch_end")
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
          print("on_batch_end")
```

Problem: during training I only see "on_train_begin" appearing in the output.

My Tensorflow version: 1.15
My Keras version: 2.2.5

Any solution ?

Thank you

p.s: I don't want to change my Keras/TF versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to call:

```
clist.on_train_batch_end(batch_num, logs)
```

in the training loop

With

```
clist = CallbackList(callbacks=self.callbacks)
```